# Are there circumstances where the Yule-Walker is preferable to OLS?

Tags: time-series, estimation, least-squares, autoregressive

Yule-Walker and OLS seem to both provide comparable estimates in AR models for large N, but Yule-Walker's estimates "are not so good" for smaller N (Chatfield, 2019, p. 84). Under what circumstances would anyone use Yule-Walker?

If none, then why teach about Yule-Walker?

Comment: [Of possible interest...](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/482685/247274)

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the point of Yule-Walker is just to be another way of estimating, but with no clear benefits